# CodeDeploy hooks running scripts in the agent instalation folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

So, I'm setting up my first application that uses CodeDeploy (EC2 + S3) and I'm having a very hard time to figure out how to run the scripts after instalation.

So I defined an AfterInstall hook in the AppSpec file refering to my bash script file in the project diretory. When the commands in the script run I get the error stating the files could not be found. So I put an `ls` command before it all and checked the logs.

My script file is running in the CodeDeploy agent folder. There are many files there that I accidentally created when I was testing but I was expecting them to be in my project root folder.

```
--Root
----init.sh
----requirements.txt
----server.py
```

**appspec.yml**

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: ./
    destination: /home/ubuntu/myapp
    runas: ubuntu
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: init.sh
      timeout: 600
```

**init.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

ls
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
python3 ./server.py
```

So when `ls` is executed, it doesn't list the files in my project root directory. I also tried ${PWD} instead of ./ and it didn't work. It is copying the script file to the agent folder and running it.

Refer to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html

This is written at the end of the above document

> The location of scripts you specify in the 'hooks' section is relative
>   to the root of the application revision bundle. In the preceding
>   example, a file named RunResourceTests.sh is in a directory named
>   Scripts. The Scripts directory is at the root level of the bundle.

But apparently it refers to the paths in the appspec file only.

Could someone help? Is it correct? I MUST use absolute paths hard-coded in the script file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes correct. The script doesn't execute in the destination folder, as you might expect. You need to hard code a reference the destination directory `/home/ubuntu/myapp` to resolve file paths in life cycle scripts.

Use cd to change the directory first:

```
cd  /home/ubuntu/myapp
ls
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
python3 ./server.py
```

Comment: it has to be from the root of the file system? Or I can just use relative path?